# How to get column names from DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I would like how to get the column names of a table from a DB2-DB.

I don't mean like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A;
```

where I would get:

```
|  ColumnA  |  ColumnB |
------------------------
  ValueA 1     ValueB 1

  ValueA 2     ValueB 2

  ValueA 3     ValueB 3
```

but more like:

```
SELECT column_name FROM TABLE A;
```

and get:

```
ColumnA, ColumnB
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For DB2 for i, this information is in

```
qsys2.syscolumns2  (for 7.1+, better performance if just looking at 1 table's columns)
qsys2.syscolumns (for any recent version)
```

ODBC/JDBC and DB2 LUW v8 compatible

```
sysibm.sqlcolumns
```

ANSI/ISO Standard

```
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
```

(note INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a synonym for QSYS2)

Full list of catalog views here:
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm

Answer (score 0):

This information is found in the table `syscat.columns`.

Comment: Not for DB2 on IBM i.

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you are doing db2 commands from a a Linux bash shell:

```
 $ db2 "DESCRIBE TABLE A" |awk '{printf "%s\t",$1} END{print}'
```

Answer (score -1):

The columns name of any table (PF) from db400 (IBM i), we can retrieve the columns name using java program.
Sample code:

```
String sql = "select * from KFILNBB.V_OCADATA";
PreparedStatement pstmt = StaticUtil.getDB2Connection().prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    
ResultSetMetaData rs1 = pstmt.getMetaData();
     
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnLabel(1));

// -------------------db2 connection----------

    public static Connection getDB2Connection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
            String DRIVER_NAME = "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver";
            
            String URL = "jdbc:as400://ibm i IP address";
             String USERNAME = "username";
            String PASSWORD = "password";
            Class.forName(DRIVER_NAME);
            return DriverManager.getConnection(URL , USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        }
```